# Finding pairs of rows with minimum difference between two quantities

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame df with columns a and t, where column "a" has strings and column "t" has integers. I want to select all the row pair(s) from the dataframe, for which the values in column "a" for that row pairs are same AND the difference in values in column "t" for that pair has minimum value. For Example:

```
df = a    t
    abc   4
    abc   3
    def   2
    abc   1
```

I want to get the following result:

```
df = a    t
     abc  4
     abc  3
```

I know we can use two for loops in the same data frame but I am looking for more efficient solution.
Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Loops might seem clumsy but I don't really see a way to reduce runtime dramatically (because you essentially would be enumerating pairwise differences the same number of times). Do you find your code inefficient?

Comment: Can you add more data to the question with expected results?

Comment: I basically want to find the pair(s) with the same value in column "a" and the pair should have minimum difference in values of column "t"

Comment: Do you ever think you'll run into a case when you have multiple pair-wise distances that are the same? Imagine you had another row `abc 0` or even `abc 2`. If those exist, what do you want to happen?

Comment: If we have multiple pairwise distances as same, both the rows should be returned. However, in your question the difference between 4 & 3 is minimum anyway, so that pair should be returned even if the rows you gave are added to the data frame

Comment: Yeah I understand that, I just didn't know if in those cases you would want all 3-4 rows listed, and how you could go about grouping the pair-wise differences. Because it could be ambiguous if you just returned `abc 4 abc 3 abc 2 abc 1`

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```
df = df.sort_values(['a', 't'], ascending=False)
diff_ = df['t']-df['t'].shift(-1)
min_idx = diff_[df['a'] == df['a'].shift(-1)].idxmin()
df.loc[min_idx:min_idx+1]
```

Output:

```
    a   t
0   abc 4
1   abc 3
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question -- OP wanted all difference pairs not just the consecutive ones. You could use````df['t'].diff() ````for the second line too.

Comment: @xyzjayne I think this method still works regardless, since you first sort the values. The minimum difference will by definition occur between consecutive rows once sorted, so this method seems okay. But it wont necessarily catch duplicate minima

Comment: @HarvIpan In what cases do we get "keyError" while using this method?
Also, can we use shift(1) instead of shift(-1)?

Comment: @DePP KeyError tells me you do not have the column that you want to access. Also, for shift, you can refer to the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). shift(1) shifts elements to next sequence while shift(-1) does the opposite. I hope it helps.

Comment: @HarvIpan Actually, the last line of the code is giving the key error. When I am following the same logic for some timestamp data, it does not seem to work.